# Result of the query does not contain the expected inner object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi !

I'm currently blocked with partial result of my query: I've executed the following one:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/index_new/_search {'query': {'range': {'collectedTime': {'gte': '2017-01-01 00:00:00Z', 'lte': 'now/d'}}}, 'size': 10}
```

It should normally return the following data (available on Kibana):

[image: Kibana_result]

But I have the following result example instead:

```
"_source": {
    "collectedTime" : "May 15th 2018, 00:50:33.000",
    "meta_lang" : "en",
    "movies" : [],
    "publish_date" : "May 15th 2018, 02:00:00.000",
    "summary" : "Late last Friday,"
}
```

It seems that `Inner object` named  `source` is not returned. May I have forgotten to add something in my query? Or there is something to add into my mapping?

Note: There is an extract of the `source` `Inner Object` in my mapping:

```
"source": {
    "properties" : {
        "category" : { "type": "text"},
        "country" : { "type": "text"},
        "lang" : { "type": "text"}
    },
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try Refreshing The Mapping in Kibana Managment Console.

Comment: I've refreshed the mapping, and the warning disappeared on Kibana. However, I still do not have the "source" inner object when I execute my query.

Comment: Have you used kibana filters for that Query and verified that you have that data in your es?

Comment: On Kibana, I've also tried my query, and every data expected are returned. However, via curl command, I do not have the "source" part.

Comment: If it works on kibana Go to Request Section of kibana and copy Query from there and check what you are doing wrong.

You will get better over view from there.

Comment: You're right ! Post your complete answer below, so I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps you will have your data.

1. Refresh Index Mappings in your Kibana Management panel.

   2. Check Filters in your kibana discovery and make sure there is data in there.
   3. Copy Filtered Query from kibana and use that one.

Hope this helps you sort your issue.

Comment: It was ! Thanks :) Also, I did not know the refresh part on the Management panel.